# How to make this simple GUI in Python?

Tags: user-interface

I'm totally new with programming, but have made some scripts for extraction data from .txt files etc. Now I am making a simple script for work, but need a simple GUI so people can run use it efficiently. The script is really simple, and consists of 4 dictionaries and a list with the keys for the values that I want to print from one of the dictionaries. What I need is a GUI that looks like the one posted. There will be 4 buttons, one for each dictionary, and the user can only pick one. On the left will be the keys, and the keys transferred to the right will be put in a list, which will be used to write the values to a .txt file. This is probably really simple, but I have no idea where to start with GUI, so I hope that someone can give me some ideas. In advance, thank you :)

Exaple: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/img/multi-select-transfer-component.png

Comment: "How to code a GUI" is not really a stack overflow question. Try googling how to make a GUI using python

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful.

Comment: first link under "how to code a GUI in python" https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm that's where you start

Answer (score 2):

It's cool that you are getting into GUI programming. Try tkinter:
    https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look :)

Comment: While you're here would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: But I have not solved my problem yet. I'm still open for help.

Comment: @JordanH this did not answer his question, he did not ask for a tutorial he wants someone to help him write the code. This question is out of scope for stack overflow

Comment: He stated "I have no idea where to start with GUI, so I hope that someone can give me some ideas". With all due respect I have correctly answered his question.

Comment: I did not want someone to write the code. I was hoping that someone could give me some tips for where to start. A tutorial is fair enough, but a sentence with a couple of modules or widgets that I should look into would be great. I though stack overflow was a great community, but it looks like getting "likes" is all that matters.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way.